# SQL inner join with count() condition, and relationnal algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have these tables:

- Movies (`id`, `name`)
- Cast (`idmovie`, `actor`)

And I would like to count the number of actors for each movie and then only get movies with more than 10 actors. I have a query to count the number of actors for each movie, which goes like this:

```
SELECT idmovie, count(actor) FROM Cast GROUP BY idmovie HAVING count(actor) > 10;
```

Now, I wonder how to get that result and join it to the Movies table.
I tried:

```
SELECT name FROM Movies INNER JOIN (SELECT idmovie FROM Cast GROUP BY idmovie HAVING count(actor) >2) Cast ON Cast.idmovie = Movies.id;
```

But it doesn't work.

I also have to translate it to relational algebra.

```
π name (σ (count(σ id = idmovie))) Movies⨝Cast
```

Which is obviously wrong...

Any help?

Comment: Do a normal `INNER JOIN` - no need for sub-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT m.name, COUNT(c.actor) AS 'ActorsCount' 
FROM Movies m INNER JOIN [Cast] c ON m.id = c.idmovie
GROUP BY m.name HAVING COUNT(c.actor) > 10;
```

Comment: I got errors from using the 'ActorsCount' and [Cast], I had to remove '' and []. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas , ahm maybe because of your dbms thats why you got an error, i assume you are using sql server, so i wrote what you want using sql server :) , anyways the important is the logic, and glad that i help. :) , next time tag your dbms. :)

Answer (score 0):

The query looks correct to me except perhaps that you aliased the nested query with `Cast` which is also the name of a table. I'm not sure what effect that'd have but I'd expect it to confuse MySQL. Try the following:

```
SELECT name FROM Movies INNER JOIN
(SELECT idmovie FROM Cast GROUP BY idmovie HAVING count(actor) >2) CastCount
ON CastCount.idmovie = Movies.id;
```

I didn't try it, but I think that'll work